# An applet without any package, and a package without any applet

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

This is contents of my smart card :

```
C:\Users\ghasemi.IT\Downloads>gp -list
AID: A000000003000000 (|........|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 6D797061636B616731 (|mypackag1|)
     Exe LOADED: (none)
```

**Q1:** Why the package with `AID: 6D797061636B616731` doesn't have any applet? Can I conclude that it is a library package?

**Q2:** Why the instance applet with `AID: A000000003000000` doesn't have any package?! Shouldn't be an applet on the card that, this is its instance?

**Q3:** Can I create another instance of this CM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes
2. it is an ISD (issues security domain), not App
3. no

One question per post please.